# Can you explain why this time complexity is nlog(n)

Tags: time-complexity

Can anyone explain what the time complexity of this problem is

```
bool containsDuplicates(vector<int> &nums)
{
 unordered_map<int,int> umap;
 for(auto itr : nums)
 {
   umap[itr]++;
 }
 
 for(auto itr: umap)
 {
   if(itr.second > 1){return true;}
 }
}
```

From my understanding first loop is O(n) and second loop is O(n) so time complexity is `O(n)+O(n) = 2 O(n)` is my understanding correct ? I read online that time complexity of above is nlog(n) is that correct ? If yes then can you please explain how ?

Answer (score 0):

if n is the number of the items in vector nums, in the first loop you pass all the items in that vector = O(n), in the second loop you pass the item in the map you create from the number in the vector so the size of  the map is n too ,this two loops together still O(n).